# Is there a way to delete all files less than x

Tags: linux, command-line

Is it possible in a single command to delete all files that match a pattern.

```
file_name_1294132_rest_of_file

rm \*(less than 1294132)\*
```

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest case where you have sane file names that contain no weird characters like new  lines, you could just do:

```
rm "$(ls | gawk -F_ '$3<1294132')"
```

There are [various reasons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) why you should avoid parsing `ls`, so here's a way around that:

```
for f in file_*; do 
   printf %s "$f" | perl -anF_ -e 'unlink() if $F[2]<1294132'; 
done
```

Comment: I'll add that you don't need to call perl once per file, and it should be a bit more defensive to catch malformed stuff (e.g. a file called "file_name"). Off the top of my head, I'd go with `perl -e 'opendir(D, "."); foreach(readdir D) {/a_(\d+)_b/; print if $1 and $1<3;}'` - which, of course, can be improved (and changed to unlink instead of print); my point is that once you realise you don't want to do a part of something in shell, it's usually best to do nothing, or as little as possible, in shell.

Comment: @Gabe I did not want to do the whole thing in Perl since I don't know if the OP knows it. I also assume that the OP knows the format of their files and that the number of interest is always the 3d field. While your perl loop can deal with `file_name`, it cannot deal with `file_10_20_30_name`. The OP never said that `_rest_of_file` cannot contain digits. Also the readdir call will o through files not matching the right pattern, subdirs etc. It all depends on what the OP want to do.

Comment: I agree with everything you say, @terdon. I just feel compelled to point out that the shell is powerful, but given that "using the shell" in reality usually means "piping together multiple independent utilities", it's difficult to be defensive, pretty much impossible to be safe; therefore, one should learn and have a more complete scripting language to hand and not be shy about switching to it. Which I'm sure you'll agree with.

Comment: @Gabe absolutely, I tend to do most things in Perl. However, the shell is actually incredibly powerful and the `for i in ` loop tends to deal with most things and `while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'` can deal with [just about everything](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020).

Answer (score 1):

I assume UNIX/Linux because of the "rm" command.

Are all the files in the same directory? If not, it complicates things a lot.

If they are, you probably have an issue with too many files in one directory and should think about your layout.

This will work, though will be slow:

```
seq 1 1294131 | xargs -i{} echo rm file_name_{}_rest_of_file
```

(of course take out the echo when you want to run the real rm)
To speed things up, I'd do globs on the files that don't need a comparison:

```
rm file_name_[1-9]_rest_of_file
rm file_name_[1-9][0-9]_rest_of_file
rm file_name_[1-9][0-9][0-9]_rest_of_file
rm file_name_[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_rest_of_file
```

etc. until your shell complained about command line length.

Another quick and dirty one would be:

```
find . -name 'file_name_*_rest_of_file' | sort -n > /tmp/files.txt
```

*edit file.txt to remove files that should **not** be deleted*

```
< /tmp/files/txt xargs rm
```

You could also write a script that tokenizes the filename into components, extracts the "count", does a comparison, and then either deletes or passes on the file. But that would probably take longer than either of the above.

Answer (score 1):

You could put this all on one line (with ';'s) and call it one command

```
for f in file_name_*_rest_of_file
do 
   n=${f//[^0-9]}
  if [[ -n $n && $n -lt 22 ]]
  then
    echo del $f
  fi
done
```

It's a bit long

```
for f in file_name_*_rest_of_file;do; n=${f//[^0-9]}; if [[ -n $n && $n -lt 22 ]]; then echo del $f; fi;done
```

${f//[^0-9]} is a bashism, and could be done with

```
nn=${f#file_name_}
n=${nn%_rest_of_file}
```

or

```
n=`echo $f | tr -C -d '[0-9]'`
```